# How to modify my App.exe.config keys at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

In my app.config I have this section

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="UserId" value ="myUserId"/>
     // several other <add key>s
</appSettings>
```

Usually I access the values using `userId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"]`

If I modify it using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"]=something`, the value is not saved to the file, and next time I load the application, it uses the old value.

How can I change the value of some app.config keys during runtime?

Comment: added c# code of that vb code in my answer

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings["UserId"].Value = "myUserId";     
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

You can read about ConfigurationManager [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

Comment: You should also have the following after that code: ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

Answer (score 3):

[Modifying app.config File](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Change_AppConfig_File.aspx)

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;

public class AppConfigFileSettings
{


    public static void UpdateAppSettings(string KeyName, string KeyValue)
    {
        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        XmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

        foreach (XmlElement xElement in XmlDoc.DocumentElement) {
            if (xElement.Name == "appSettings") {

                foreach (XmlNode xNode in xElement.ChildNodes) {
                    if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value == KeyName) {
                        xNode.Attributes[1].Value = KeyValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        XmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are special classes for working with app.config - you don't have to do it manualy

Comment: @Rafał Spacjer  - i know that you can go for the special classes that already available in .net framwork but this just one solution that i applied in my project

Comment: but I don't think it's a good idea to  invent wheel every time we need to do something. Needed functionality can be done in 3 lines of code instead of more then 10.

Comment: It may be desired not to re-write the entire file, just to change one element. And since the 3 lines of code do that, it surely winds up doing more actual 'work' in more lines, anyway. This ends up being a single line of code, where used. ;)

Comment: Isn't app.config only used at compile time? Hence the myExecutable.exe.config etc.

Comment: No. It's used at runtime as the final say in the application's configuration, aside from programmatic overrides. These values aren't compiled in, at all, for the standard app.config file placed alongside any standard .net program, unless you use the VS "Settings" interface to create it. And, even then, that just compiles in convenient accessors and defaults. The values in the file will still override those defaults, at runtime. This configuration scheme is also layered, from the local appname.exe.config all the way to machine level settings that your application can access.

Answer (score 3):

After changing the value, probably u will be not saving the Appconfig document.

```
// update    
  settings[-keyname-].Value = "newkeyvalue"; 
//save the file 
  config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);   
//relaod the section you modified 
  ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

On a side note.

If something in your app.config needs to change at runtime...its possible there's a better place to keep that variable.

App.config is used for constants. At worst case something with a one time initialization.

Comment: I agree, however there are cases where a connection string may inappropriately be entered in clear-text and you'd like to encrypt that on the fly IMO.

Comment: If you want to keep using the default configuration manager but be able to load external config files at startup, it becomes necessary.

Comment: Runtime at the start or end of your application is still runtime.

Comment: For me it's a good idea to not use extra files merely for the benefit of simplicity. If there is already a .config file around and it can be used without conflicts, why have an extra file in a folder?

Comment: Outside of unit testing, I strongly agree. However, in the context of a unit test, it can be quite handy to be able to dynamically update config values to increase test coverage.

Comment: I some cases, such as referencing a webservice, VS auto dumps the imported service endpoints into the app config. Once deployed the endpoint host has to be dynamically updated to make the correct service calls. My point is that in some cases this is the only way. Although it is definitely not the best way.