# Changing App Settings during run time

Tags: c#

So I was looking at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468342/how-to-modify-my-app-exe-config-keys-at-runtime) to figure out how to do it. And, it works for when I run my project multiple times. However, from my understanding, the save only occurs when the project closes. What I would like to do is to save it when I need to during my code, so that during the same run time, I can accessed the previously saved files. Does anybody know how to approach this problem?

This is what I'm using to save my app settings at run time:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["CurrentPromoId"].Value = promo_id.ToString();
config.AppSettings.Settings["Date"].Value = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about [RefreshSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx)?

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```